# How to create a custom page via shopify app on online store

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am creating an app whose functionality is to create a new page upon its installation in the online store.

I created a test app using the shopify CLI and added a webhook on APP_UNINSTALLATION topic in gdpr.js. I attached the callback URL to a async function to create a new page on the online store using this guide : https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-07/resources/page#post-pages. My code :-

```
gdpr.js

  APP_UNINSTALLED: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks/create-new-page",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log("payload : ", payload);
    },
  }
```

```
index.js

async function createNewPageUponInstall(session) {

    const newPage = new shopify.api.rest.Page({session: session});
    newPage.title = "Dynamic App Page"
    newPage.body_html = "<p>This is a new page</p>"

    await newPage.save({
      update: true,
    });
}

app.post("/api/webhooks/create-new-page", async (_req, res) => {
  try {
    await createNewPageUponInstall(res.locals.shopify.session);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error handling webhook:", error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

The app is unable to create the pages as per my expectations. P.S. I couldn't find a webhook topic on APP_INSTALLATION hence was testing the behavior with APP_UNINSTALLATION. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a page is to make an API call to the endpoint designated for that purpose. The RestAPI has one you can use.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-07/resources/page

You can see from that the parameters to send, and the expected result.